# What is the appropriate return value when the pattern matched is Nil and we want to return Nil?

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and functional programming in general. So here's my doubt.

In a function with pattern matching, when `case Nil` is matched, and we want to return `Nil`, should we return `Nil` or the data type itself? For example,

```
def drop[A](l: List[A], n: Int): List[A] = {
    if (n <= 0) l
    else l match {
        case Nil => Nil
        case Cons(_, t) => drop(t, n - 1)
    }
}
```

This is a function which drops the first `n` head elements from a Singly Linked List. Here, for the first case, should I return `Nil` (maybe as a good practice) or should I return `l` (because it then we won't have to construct the `Nil` object)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is only one singleton instance of the `Nil` object. When you write `Nil` you don't create a new one every time, you just use the only one that exists.

It's typically best to write `Nil` because it's more readable. At least that's what I've always read and written.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only one instance of Nil so it does not matter since it is the actual same object.

---

Now the real question is: **what is more readable?**

- If you want to make it clear that when you get `Nil`, then `Nil` is returned, then write `Nil => Nil`
- If it seems more logical to return `l`, even if it is actually `Nil`, then write `Nil => l`

IMHO, in your case, `Nil => Nil` is more clear to me.

Comment: Can you please give an example for the case where the return value is `Nil` but writing `l` makes the code more readable? I've seen instances where I have an accumulator initialized to `Nil` which is returned because it may or may not accumulate more values. But I haven't seen the case you mentioned yet.

Answer (score 0):

If that `Nil => Nil` is really offending your sensibilities within your main logic flow, you might consider making enrich-my-library-style implicit class to hide it within a new method:

```
implicit class ListWithIfNonEmpty[A](list: List[A]) {
  /**
   * Replaces a list with a new one in the case that it is
   * not empty. newList is probably a conversion of the original
   * list, but the original list is available in the caller's 
   * scope, so no need to pass it as a parameter.
   */
  def ifNonEmpty[B](newList: => List[B]): List[B] = list match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case _ => newList
  }
}
```

And then your `drop` method becomes a slightly cleaner:

```
def drop[A](l: List[A], n: Int): List[A] = l.ifNonEmpty {
  if (n <= 0) l else drop(l.tail, n - 1)
}
```

Perhaps there's a less awkward name for the new method. This sort of thing is only a big win for your main logic flow in those cases where the method name makes the semantics you're going for really obvious. But you get the drift.